Can't close out of pop up box with selenium
I'm trying to download a pdf at the following link:
https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/view/lcd.aspx?lcdid=39763&ver=8
Most documents at this website have the a pop up for accepting a license which I can close using
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnAcceptLicense").click()

The link above has another pop up afterward that contains a "Close" button. I can find with
elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-footer").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn")

But when I run elem.click(), I get a ElementNotInteractableException.
Here is what I've written so far:
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/view/lcd.aspx?lcdid=39859&ver=4"

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(0.5)
# Accept license
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnAcceptLicense").click()
time.sleep(0.5)
# Close pop second pop up (fails here)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-footer").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn").click()

# Download document
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnDownload").click() 


Check the working code below, also note that the code has been refactored by using selenium's waits instead of time.sleep().
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/view/lcd.aspx?lcdid=39859&ver=4")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Accept license
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnAcceptLicense"))).click()

# Click on Close button of the second pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-page-action='Clicked the Tracking Sheet Close button.']"))).click()


Thanks for answering and also adding the WebDriverWait which is a lot better

For the second pop-up (the "Tracking Sheet" one), you can use By.CSS_SELECTOR with this:
"div#modalTrackingSheet div button".
The full line for closing it:
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#modalTrackingSheet div button").click()

Try using XPATH instead to click the close button.
Replace this line:
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-footer").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn").click()

with:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/form/div[3]/div[7]/div/div/div[3]/button").click()


its just a terrible xpath. -1
